# Google Docs AddOn not creating menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have an AddOn published for Google Docs and I've run into an issue where the custom menu isn't being created.

All of the testing through the Apps Script options works in all modes (`AuthMode.NONE`, `LIMITED`, and `FULL`). I'm not calling any functions that require authorization in `onInstall(e)` or `onOpen(e)`. When I load a document, the console logs an error, `Google Apps Script: Custom menus must contain at least one item.`

**Code**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
    .addItem('Run', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}
```

I'm really scratching my head with this one. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Put your `onInstall()` function at the very top of code.gs and `onOpen()` afterwards.  I and others have experienced strange results also, and I think having `onInstall()` at the very beginning makes a difference.  I do not know why and can not prove anything.  It can't hurt to try my advice.

Comment: The original script had it that way, but the Google documentation had it reversed. I'll flip it back because I haven't seen a difference one way or the other. Just very strange because I can reproduce the issue that users are reporting, but can't figure out why.

Comment: You should post this issue in the [Add-on Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code, and of course you have to add a html named "htmlFileName" to the left bar on script editor.

```
function onOpen(e) {    
DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
.addItem("Run Html", 'showMyHtml')
.addToUi();
}
function onInstall(e) {
onOpen(e);
}
function showMyHtml() {
var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('htmlFileName')
.setTitle('My Title')
.setWidth(600);
DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```